# Opencellid request location

Tags: python, geolocation, cellid

I have an csv that contain the information of cell towers. MMC, MNC, LAC, ID.
The python script I wrote read from the csv file 
Iterate through rows and extract the information of the cell in a dictionary:

```
Cell={"MMC":6050, "MNC":01, "LAN":213, "ID":3657, "TX":230, "RX":960, "LONG":None, "LAT":None}
```

Now, I want to connect to opencellid  to get the location of the cell.
It maybe something like this:

```
data={"MMC":6050, "MNC":01, "LAN":213, "ID":3657}
res=requests.post("https://www.opencellid.com/location/search.php", data)
res.json()
```

I don't have a clear idea about this. And I don't know how to deal with the Opencellid API.
I really need help?

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://unwiredlabs.com/docs/?python#geocoding 
You will be able to see a small sample of python code on how to send a request and print a response. You are missing your token as well so make sure to get one and send it in your data field.